# How to split column containing date and time when null values are present in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a column that has data as such

```
df <- data.frame(request_time = c("2020-12-31 13:05:00", NULL, "2020-11-14 02:04:01")
```

I want to split the request_time column to extract just the the date. Hoping to have a new column called request_date.

I was trying to do the following:

```
df$request_date <- as.Date(df$request_time)
```

But this returns an error saying the "character string is not in a standard unambioguous format" Im assuming dates due to the NULLS present. How can I get past this?

Comment: Are you sure your values are NULL? Because you can't have a NULL value in your vector. If you run your sample code (after adding a missing closing parenthesis), you see it only has two rows. Did you mean NA values rather than NULL? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `as_date` function together with `ymd` from lubridate package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(request_time = ymd(as_date(request_time)))
```

output:

```
  request_time
1   2020-12-31
2   2020-11-14
```

**OR**

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate(request_time, c("date", "time"), sep=" ", remove = FALSE)
```

```
        request_time       date     time
1 2020-12-31 13:05:00 2020-12-31 13:05:00
2 2020-11-14 02:04:01 2020-11-14 02:04:01
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the date using `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
f %>%
  mutate(request_time = str_extract(request_time, "[0-9-]+"))
  request_time
1   2020-12-31
2   2020-11-14
```

in `base R`:

```
f$request_time <- str_extract(f$request_time, "[0-9-]+")
```

Comment: `str_extract` is not a base R function

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL` part is not clear.  If it is a string `"NULL"`, the `as.Date` should return `NA`.  Otherwise, `NULL` cannot exist as such.  It may be a `list` column (which is not clear)

```
df$request_time <- as.Date(df$request_time)
```

-output

```
df$request_time
[1] "2020-12-31" NA           "2020-11-14"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(request_time = c("2020-12-31 13:05:00", "NULL", "2020-11-14 02:04:01"))
```